# try-block not working when function is used as argument

Tags: python, function, exception, return, try-catch

I have a function which I pass to another function:

```
def func1(a, b):
    return a/b
```

The second function is meant to handle exceptions similar to the one raised by `func1`:

```
def func2(func):
    try:
        return func
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print("0")
```

If I pass

```
func2(func1(1,2))
```

The output is `0.5`, as expected. However, `func2(func1(1,0))` raises a `ZeroDivisionError` that is not caught by the `except` statement:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input> in <module>
----> 1 func2(func1(1,0))

<ipython-input> in func1(a, b)
      1 def func1(a, b):
----> 2     return a/b

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Can anyone clarify why the except block is not entered in this example?

```
def func3(a,b):
    try:
        a/b
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print("0")
```

with input `func3(1,0)` returns `0`, as expected.

**Background**: I have a code with multiple API calls, which sometimes return a Connection error. I want to put all these calls inside a function which attempts a retry after a few seconds.

Comment: The actual computation takes place one `func1`. So Use the exception handler on `func1`

Comment: Use try except in func1 because func2 will only return output of func1 and no need of try-except there.

Comment: Thats what I did in `func3` . However, I have many functions similar to `func1` which should all be handled in the same way (i.e. through `func2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written `func2` wrong and are calling it wrong.

Try this instead:

```
def func2(func):
    try:
        return func()
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print("0")
```

and call it like this:

```
func2(lambda:func1(1,2))
```

**Update:**

Also note that `func2` will return the return value of `func()` if there is no ZeroDivisionError exception, but when there is an exception it returns `None`.

Answer (score 2):

If you must put the check in `func2` you will need to make sure that the computation is happening inside `func2`. In your case, the call is `func2(func1(1,0))`. So what is happening under the hood is, when `func2` calls `func1(1,0)`, it is not computing the `func1` inside it, instead it is taking the value of `func(1,0)`, i.e. it is asking `func1` to do its calculation in its own scope, and return only the value. `func1` encounters a `ZeroDivisionError` without entering the `Try` block of `func2`. Your actual function call becomes `func2(return_val_of_func1(1,0))`. So you are essentially checking whether the value of `func1` throws any `ZeroDivisionError`, which is not possible. So instead, what you can do is:

```
def func1(a, b):
    return a/b

def func2(func1,a,b):
    try:
        return func1(a,b)
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print("0")

func2(func1,1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

func2 will never return ZeroDivisionError as this error was never raised in the try block. In the try block, you are just returning the output of func1 which will never throw an error.

You can try:

```
def func1(a, b):
    try:
        return a/b
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print("0")


def func2(func):
    return func
```

Comment: Your `func2()` does nothing!